# Carregar linhas em listview a partir de um OpenDialog

Tags: delphi, listview

Preciso carregar items de um arquivo de texto num `Listview` usando `Opendialog`, como preceder?

Existe alguma propriedade `LoadFromFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `LoadFromFile` não é disponível no [`Listview`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TListView.html), o que você pode fazer é carregar as informações do arquivo num [`StringList`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList) e popular o `Listview` com [`TListItem`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TListItem.html). Veja um exemplo:

```pascal
procedure AddItemsListview(Listview: TListView; Arquivo: string);
Var
  Items: TStringList;
  Item: TListItem;
  I: Integer;
begin
Items := TStringList.Create;
try
  Items.LoadFromFile(Arquivo);
  for I := 0 to Items.Count -1 do begin
    Item := Listview.Items.Add;
    Item.Caption := Items[I]; // Coloca o valor na primeira coluna do Listview
  end;
finally
  Items.Free;
end;
end;
```

E para utilizar o método acima, supondo que você já adicionou `OpenDialog`, faça o seguinte:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
OpenDialog1.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)); // Abre o diálogo no diretório do programa
OpenDialog1.Filter := 'Arquivos de texto (.txt) | *.txt'; // Somente arquivos de texto

if OpenDialog1.Execute = false then exit;
AddItemsListview(ListView1, OpenDialog1.FileName);
end;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, porém teria como eu limitar a quantidade de items neste listview? por exemplo, de 600 items ele carregar apenas 200?

Comment: @Fake No laço `for` que é feito no método `AddItemsListview`, você pode fazer algo assim: `if I = 200 then Break;`. Isso irá adicionar somente os *200* primeiros itens ao `Listview`.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado.

Comment: Teria como limitar os items do TStringList?

Comment: @Fake Eu acredito que não seja possível, a [documentação](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStrings_LoadFromFile@string.html) pelo menos não diz nada sobre isso.